# Filling array[19] with random values. | c# WP7

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-7, random, numbers

**Question:**

Hey, I am trying to design a method that will fill an Array[19] with 20 random numbers, that will be different every time the program is run.

I'd like these values to be between 1-4 and these values will activate/deactivate a series of if statements depending on the outcome number.

I have no idea how to start this system, do I make a foreach loop?

**Example:**

I run my program and for example the random feature sets the values:

Array[4] = 3

Array[5] = 4

So that means the If statement for "3" would be activated, and it means that the other If statement for "4" will be activated... and the rest won't be activated.

This continues until all twenty array values have been processed.

**Problem:**

No idea how to lay out this code, relatively new c# programmer, even examples of something like this would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters a 20-value array would be declared int[20] (not 19). The amount in the [] for the declaration is the number of elements. Thereafter we index into the array using a 0-based index. So 19 is the max index for an element declared as int[20].

To answer your question, a for loop (and probably not a foreach) is what you want here:

```
int[] flags = new int[20];
Random rng = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < flags.Length; i++)
   flags[i] = rng.Next(1, 5);
```

To explain, you loop through each index (using i as the iteration variable) assigning your random number each time. The arguments are (1, 5) because Random uses an inclusive min (1 is possible) and an exclusive max (5 is not).

As an aside, make sure to use one Random instance per class (and possibly per program). Recreating the random class can decrease the randomness of the generated numbers if you call the creating function multiple times in a short period of time.

**EDIT**: Rereading your question I realized you may be asking about how to process such an array. I would still use a for loop, and run your if statements inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < flags.Length; i++)
{
    if (flags[i] == 3)
    ...

    //Or
    switch(flags[i])
    {
        case 3:
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

You would probably need some sort of parallel array with the "on/off" flags for each of the features. Without more code/description from you it is hard to say.

Comment: I believe c# has a switch case structure?

Comment: _Recreating the random class decreases the randomness of the generated numbers._ This statement is a bit misleading. Creating multiple `Random` objects in a tight loop will cause the same seed to be passed to the constructor, which in turn gives the same series of pseudo-random output numbers. As long as the seeds are different for each `Random` object, they should give sufficiently random outputs between each object.

Comment: Absolutley. A switch is really a glorified if/else of course but that would be a valid way of processing. Added the switch to my post.

Comment: @IchabodClay my understanding is that it is considered bad practice to put a Random class object as a function level variable, and to always put it at the class level. Does that match your understanding?

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to try this right now. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @LordTakkera Putting the `Random` object as a class member/property for the most part avoids the pitfall of creating multiples in a short time span (unless you create multiples of that class really quickly as well). In my personal opinion I wouldn't consider it bad practice, but there might be people that disagree with me :) Just have to make sure your code runs the way you want it to.

Comment: @IchabodClay Ok, I think we are on the same page, I edited my answer to attempt and address your comments. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to keep the array around, or just process 20 random numbers between 1 and 4?

You can build the array like this:

```
var a = new int[20];
var r = new Random();
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) {
  a[i] = r.Next(1, 5);
}
```

If you don't need to keep the array, you can rework that code to look something like:

```
var r = new Random();
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) {
    switch(r.Next(1, 5)) {
        case 1: 
           // do something
           break;
        case 2: 
           // do something
           break;
        case 3: 
           // do something
           break;
        case 4: 
           // do something
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The first issue is "...different every time the program is run" - one way to do that is to start with the system that generates the current time and use that as a starting variable.
In Objective C:

```
     NSDate *now=[[NSDate alloc] init];
     double nowValue=[now timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
     [now release];
```

Then seed a function called srandom() and generate random()%4+1:

```
     srandom(nowValue);
     for(int I=0;I<20;I++){
         Array[I]=random()%4+1;
     }
```

Comment: This question is about C#... not sure how writing the standard rng code from Objective C is relevant.